# Convergence of $\prod(1-\frac{1}{n^z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the convergence domain of $$\prod(1-\frac{1}{n^z})$$ where $n \ge 2$?

I found that it converges absolutely for $\Re(z)>1$, does not converge for real number $x \leq 1$. (I used $\sum \frac{1}{n^x}$ for these.) But what's it about other points?

Comment: @joriki yes, the definition is the convergence to nonzero.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I wasn't aware of that definition.